# Waiting for a submitted job to finish in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: multithreading, oracle, plsql

I'm looking for the equivalent of Java's thread.join() in PL/SQL. I.e. I want to kick off a number of jobs (threads), and then wait for them to finish.

How is this possible in PL/SQL?

I'm thinking of using dbms_job.submit (I know it's deprecated). dbms_scheduler is also an alternative.

My code:

```
DECLARE
  jobno1 number;
  jobno2 number;
BEGIN

  dbms_job.submit(jobno1,'begin dbms_lock.sleep(10); dbms_output.put_line(''job 1 exit'');end;');
  dbms_job.submit(jobno2,'begin dbms_lock.sleep(10); dbms_output.put_line(''job 2 exit'');end;');

  dbms_job.run(jobno1);
  dbms_job.run(jobno2);

  //Need code to Wait for jobno1 to finish
  //Need code to Wait for jobno2 to finish

END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the solution from Adam Hawkes using DBMS_SCHEDULER chains. Didn't know about that since I'm still using DBMS_JOB and not having rewritten code yet.

Anyway... the solution I currently use for this is a combination of DBMS_JOB (although you should probably use DBMS_SCHEDULER since DBMS_JOB is deprecated as you noted) and DBMS_ALERT.

Jobs are created using DBMS_JOB. Then we wait for the jobs to complete using dbms_alert.register and dbms_alert.waitany. Each job when it completes uses dbms_alert.signal. There may be a problem if the job completes and signals before the parent is ready but I'm sure you could work around that.

I'm guessing that the DBMS_SCHEDULER chains are probably the way you should do this now but am just adding my answer for completeness.

Comment: An equally good solution if you're still using `DBMS_JOB` instead of `DBMS_SCHEDULER`!

Comment: +1, nice idea .. any ideas on how I would wait for the 2 jobs to finish ( like you mentioned there will be a probability that a job will finish before the waitany step is invoked). One solution that I could think of is to have both jobs throw the same event, and then catch it twice ... alternatives?

Comment: @vicjugador: The short answer is that when creating the jobs we add an identifier (the identifier is created using `DBMS_RANDOM`) to a collection. Then when the job signals back, we remove it from the collection. Once the collection is empty we move on. There is probably a better way to handle this though. You could just assume that you've created 2 jobs and got 2 signals back so you're done.

Answer (score 12):

This is accomplished using Chains in the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` job scheduling. The [Oracle Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/schedadmin.htm#BAJHFHCD) has examples which accomplish what you want. Basically, you define steps, small portions of code, with an execution structure. In your example, your first step would be a start step (which would typically do initialization), then you'd have two steps which run in parallel (jobno1 and jobno2), and then a final step which would activate once both parallel jobs complete.

Comment: +1, nice I didn't know about chaining ability in dbms_scheduler ... though I'm still not sure how I would wait for the last 2 steps (run in parallel) to finish before my block my finishes.