# Continually check for an Oracle record at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, oracle-apex

I basically have a page that when loads, reads an Oracle SQL table for a specific record id that may not currently exist at the point as it may take up to a minute to insert this specific record into the table.

Based on this, I need a means of showing a "Loading Image" while it waits for the record to exist, so has to wait. Once it does, I want to remove the loading image and present the user with the record details. I am using Oracle Application Express 4.2 for this.

My question is not so much the loading/hiding of the image but how to continually check for the record within the Oracle table, during page load.

Either I receive the record successfully and then hide the image or say after 1 minute, I dismiss the checking of the record and present the user with a message indicating that no record was found.

Comment: how do create this record? Is it a procedure you kick off, or is it a job that runs, or some process?

Comment: Hi Tom, it' actually a package procedure that kicks this job off from another Oracle APEX app, which then runs in the background, but after this job is created from this app, the user can then, from this app, click a link that then calls the process I have described in my original post above, that is, calls another Oracle APEX application. It is here during page load, I wish to show the loading image, until this job actually comes into existence, within my table. Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english. I will try help you.

1. Make your "Loading image" always visible on the page. There is no need to show it on load, you only need to hide it at proper moment.
2. Add Application Process to your application. Name it for example "GET_MY_ROW". Process must check your event, and return some flag, for example 1 or 0.

Example:

```
declare
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*)
   into l_cnt
   from table1 t
   where id = 12345;
  if l_cnt > 0 then
    htp.p(1);
  else
    htp.p(0);
  end if;
end;
```

3.3 Add javascript code as page load event (for example by Dynamic Actions):

Javascript code:

```
var myInterval = setInteral(function {
    var get = new htmldb_Get(null,$v('pFlowId'),'APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_MY_ROW',$v('pFlowStepId'));
    get.GetAsync(function(pRequest) {
        if (pRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (pRequest.responseText == 1) {
                alert('Record loaded successfully');
                // add function call, hiding your "Loading image" here
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        };
    });
    get = null;
}, 5000); //check every 5 seconds

setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Sorry, no record was found. Try again later.');
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 60000); // fail after 1 minute
```

Answer (score 0):

Since NoGotnu already answered, I'll put this here:

Is there any reason for the procedure to be called through a job? Is it the only way to create the required record? Is the job called anywhere else? Why not call the procedure directly when the required page has been submitted and show the loading icon there? When it finishes, the user knows it has finished. That would involve a lot less fiddling around as you can make apex show a processing graphic on page submit. You could then just inform the user on the other page that the process has not been ran yet and they'd have to do that first.

Secondly, while NoGotnu's answer will work, I'd like to point out that in apex 4.2 you should use the [apex.server namespace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/javascript_api.htm#BGBJEFDJ) instead of the never documented htmldb_Get construction. [apex.server.process](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/javascript_api.htm#BGBIIJFC) is a clean implementation of the jQuery ajax setup. 
NoGotnu's code translated:

```
apex.server.process( "GET_MY_ROW"
                    , null
                    , {  dataType: text
                       , success: function(pData){
                          if (pData == 1) {
                             clearInterval(myInterval);
                             alert('Record loaded successfully');
                          };
                         }
                      }
                   );
```

The call doesn't really need to be async though, but ok.

Another option would be to implement a "long poll" instead of firing the ajax event every 5 seconds. A long poll will just initiate a call to the server and wait for a response. As long as the server is busy, the client will wait. To achieve this you could use dbms_alert, as suggested in [Waiting for a submitted job to finish in Oracle PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599630/waiting-for-a-submitted-job-to-finish-in-oracle-pl-sql)
You'd signal an alert in the plsql code of the job, and in the ondemand process code register an interest in the alert and use waitone/any with a 60 second timeout. Presto long poll.

Comment: Hello, Tom! Thanks for your answer. I knew about apex.server.process but i tried to give an example of universal method, that works even at APEX 3.x. About long poll - i think that in this simple task, long poll will be excessive (or redundant? - my english is bad). But you are right anyway ;)

Comment: @NoGotnu If people are on 4.2 but persist in using htmldb_Get they deserve punishment honestly ;) I understand it was useful, but still consider a jQuery implementation far superior even though it takes a couple of extra lines. To me, it is just more transparent, and I love how apex has expanded on it and gives us a more standardized control. As for long poll: yes, this may be a bit overkill. Still, it should not be hard to implement by using dbms_alert, and kills some of the tediousness having to be done in javascript. But hey, both ways work and having options is a good thing!

Comment: @Tom Looking at your "long pull" suggestion, would really appreciate an example as I've actually raised another thread in SO. Pls see" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825441/how-to-use-oracle-dbms-alert-within-oracle-apex